# Wordpress post customising

Tags: php, wordpress

i was wondering if this is feasible.

Supposing my i want to divide my post ...  Lets say, i have all my post side by side in 2 rows.

Lets say a total of 8 from the category (Mypost)

Now assuming, i want to have a static  between the first 2 rows and the rest of the columns below, is this feasible?

Also assuming i want latest post to show on the 2 up rows and the old post to move below my div.

I have tried , but did not come out with any feasible solution.

Great if someone could be able to assist.  I have content.php where all my contents are being generated and index.php being the front end.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

using two WP query may help you ,use this one for latest post

```
         <?php query_posts('category_name=Mypost&showposts=5');?>
```

And for the older posts use

```
         <?php query_posts('category_name=Mypost&offset=5');?>
```

I really don't understand your problem clearly,hope this is what you want

Comment: Hi, thanks for the concern. What i am treying to archive is... Suppposing 1 have 8 post in my post categorie-  

1    2

Comment: Please what i am trying to archieve is this:
My current blog post 2 post on a row
1-------2 (row 1)
3-------4 (row 2)
5--------6(row3)

Now, supposing , I want to have a banner before  row 2, but after row 1.
Please how do I archiev this? My current block posts the new article as the first. So i will like to archieve that when ever a new post is posted, one from the top moves to the other rows below.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU Akhila -  Ok, i needed to edit the code a little bit - This code works!:)

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=post&showposts=2'); ?>

<?php query_posts('category_name=post&showposts=100&offset=2'); ?>
```